# Nodes unexpectedly closing in Mariadb Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, percona, galera

I've setup 3 node galera cluster for my application, there is a certain stored procedure in my application that creates a table temporarily(Not TEMPORARY TABLE), the table is created dynamically and executed. Some CRUD operation is done on the table muptiple times and after its usage is completed it is dropped at the end of the stored procedure. 
The problem is that everytime I run this particular stored procedure 2 out of my 3 node fails and shuts down automatically. 
Here is the Log from the node that fails :-

```
    05 seqnos (l: 38, g: 47, s: 46, d: 46, ts: 186965868554819)
150423  8:31:35 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to apply trx 47 4 times
150423  8:31:35 [ERROR] WSREP: Node consistency compromized, aborting...
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Closing send monitor...
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Closed send monitor.
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: terminating thread
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: joining thread
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closing backend
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,4d2adf77-e972-11e4-be7e-6bcb3d5c882f,3) memb {
    849bbb26-e981-11e4-9f9f-f37ebca03acf,0
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
    4d2adf77-e972-11e4-be7e-6bcb3d5c882f,0
    634f32cb-e972-11e4-a226-bf661daf79d7,0
})
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = no, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closed
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Received NON-PRIMARY.
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Shifting SYNCED -> OPEN (TO: 47)
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Received self-leave message.
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [0, 0]
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Received SELF-LEAVE. Closing connection.
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> CLOSED (TO: 47)
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: RECV thread exiting 0: Success
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: recv_thread() joined.
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Closing replication queue.
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: Closing slave action queue.
150423  8:31:35 [Note] WSREP: /usr/sbin/mysqld: Terminated.
150423 08:31:35 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150423 08:31:35 mysqld_safe WSREP: not restarting wsrep node automatically
150423 08:31:35 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /mnt/mysql/db3-prod.pid ended
```

is There any particular I can solve this without modifying the internal structure of the stored procedure.

The output of

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'default%'; is 

+---------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name             | Value  |
+---------------------------+--------+
| default_master_connection |        |
| default_regex_flags       |        |
| default_storage_engine    | InnoDB |
| default_week_format       | 0      |
+---------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Please show us the Stored Procedure.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'default%';`

Comment: I've updated the variable in the question

Comment: What version are you running?  5.6.3 has `default_tmp_storage_engine`, independent of `default_storage_engine`; I don't know whether that feature has made it into PXC or MariaDB 10.x yet.  Suggest you grumble at them.

Comment: Here's the info on Server version: 10.0.16-MariaDB-wsrep MariaDB Server, wsrep_25.10.r4144